# Using XSSF POI removeRow(row) API, does not clear cell comments, if present

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI XSSF APIs to remove one or more rows from an excel sheet.
Below is the code for deleting multiple rows in a single activity.

```
for (int i = startRowIndexToDel; i <= endRowIndexToDel; i++) {              
            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
            if (row != null) {
                sheet.removeRow(row);

            }               
}
if (endRowIndexToDel < lastRowIndex) {
            sheet.shiftRows(endRowIndexToDel + 1, lastRowIndex,
                    startRowIndexToDel - (endRowIndexToDel + 1));
}
```

The above code works okay when the rows that I need to delete do not have cell comments. 
When they have cell comments, the comments stay behind and are assigned to rows that are shifted to the deleted row's place, which is not what I want.

Same is the case when I need to delete only one row and that happens to be the last row. 
In that case, my code does not shift the rows since it is the last row.

I am aware of the fact that using removeRow() does not 'delete' the row, as happens when we right click on an excel row and choose delete, and instead clears the row of data as happens when we choose a row in excel and click on the delete keyboard button. I also noticed that the latter action also does not clear cell comments.

I would like to know if anyone else had noticed this issue and what was your fix for it. I can parse through all the cells in the row that I want to delete and remove cell comments if they are present, but I do not want to do this.